# Field seems to have become binary field on update from Lucene 3.6 to Lucene 4.1

Tags: java, lucene

Strange test failure after converting code from Lucene 3.6 to Lucene 4.1

```
public void testIndexPuid() throws Exception {

        addReleaseOne();
        RAMDirectory ramDir = new RAMDirectory();
        createIndex(ramDir);

        IndexReader ir = IndexReader.open(ramDir);
        Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(ir);
        Terms terms = fields.terms("puid");
        TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);
        termsEnum.next();
        assertEquals("efd2ace2-b3b9-305f-8a53-9803595c0e38", termsEnum.term());
    }
```

returns:

Expected :efd2ace2-b3b9-305f-8a53-9803595c0e38
Actual   :[65 66 64 32 61 63 65 32 2d 62 33 62 39 2d 33 30 35 66 2d 38 61 35 33 2d 39 38 30 33 35 39 35 63 30 65 33 38]

It seems to be adding the field as a binary field rather than a text field, but I checked and the field is being added using the deprecated

new Field("puid", value, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS, new KeywordAnalyzer())

so shouldn't that work the same way as before ?

Comment: Doh, my bad missing utf8ToString(), line should be:
assertEquals("efd2ace2-b3b9-305f-8a53-9803595c0e38", termsEnum.term().utf8ToString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, my bad missing utf8ToString(), line should be: assertEquals("efd2ace2-b3b9-305f-8a53-9803595c0e38", termsEnum.term().utf8ToString()); – Paul Taylor Feb 19 at 22:20